# How to load JS file without refreshing the page with vue js

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.7, webpack-4

I'm using vue-js and have write some external JavaScript code. The JS work only when I refresh the page. But, in single page application no need to refresh the page. How apply JS without refreshing the page ? Bellow is my JS code which need page refresh to work.

```
 $('.toggle_description').click(function () {
  description = $(this).prev();
  description.toggle();
  if (description.css('display') == 'none') {
    $(this).html('نمایش');
    $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
  } else {
    $(this).html('پنهان');
    $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-primary');
    // $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean `external` js code ?? can you please share your code

Comment: external js code means custom. and here is my code. `$('.toggle_description').click(function () {
  description = $(this).prev();
  description.toggle();
  if (description.css('display') == 'none') {
    $(this).html('نمایش');
    $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
  } else {
    $(this).html('پنهان');
    $(this).removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-primary');
    // $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
  }
});
`